# Power BI multiple conditions for countifs

Tags: powerbi, dax, countif

I am trying to achieve the countifs here for the following combination item and code.

Column A&B has Item and code and column C my status.

1.if same item has "YP" after the code and there is no "YP" after the code then my status is "NotOKay".

Example;

[image]

2.There is no "YP" after the code for the same item then my status is "Okay".

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0M9U.png)

Comment: Is there always will be a dash "-" before the string YP?

Comment: yes. There is always dash "-" before starting the YP.

Comment: What are you trying to count? OK rows? Distinct OK items?

Comment: I am new  to Power Bi. In Excel I am trying to make a formula countifs+ find or search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below code applicable for both **measure** and **column**-

```
ok_not_ok = 

VAR item_count = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_2[item]),
    ALLEXCEPT(your_table_2,your_table_2[item])
)

VAR item_count_with_yp =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_2[item]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_2,your_table_2[item]),
        RIGHT(your_table_2[code],3) = "-YP"            
    )
) + 0

RETURN IF(
    item_count_with_yp = 0 || item_count=item_count_with_yp, 
    "OK", 
    "NOT OK"
)
```

Here is sample output-

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I tried your measure but I got all of them is "Okay". Maybe I made some mistake can you please advise.

Comment: I don't know how to attached snapshot here. could you please have a look at the "enter image description here".

Comment: HOW can share the file here?

Comment: "enter image description here" go to my in my original question

Comment: you can keep file in Drive and share the link. Can you say how 235 got OK?

Comment: it item cannot be two different things at the same time. like with dash or without dash.

Comment: but the same item can be with dash or without dash.

Comment: any advice please

Comment: Logic for 235 not clear yet. Provide sample data that explain all scenarios. Then explain logic for all cases to generate output in the measure.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The logic here the same item,can not be the code (staring with number and dash(AL0140-YP) and starting number only without dash (AL0140). The secound one the same item, the code can be same without dash or without dash.

Comment: Hi @Jack, thanks for your detail explanation. Things are much clear now. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Hi. Good morning. Thanks for your feedback. I am sorry still I am getting all of them is "oky". https://www.dropbox.com/s/2swhfpbsy9ewzxw/SOF-R_R.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Hi. Good morning. Thanks for your feedback. I am sorry still I am getting all of them is "oky". Herewith attached the link for your reference. could you please advise what is the problem and also how it's working? can you please explain the logic so it will help to understand the Power BI world.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/2swhfpbsy9ewzxw/SOF-R_R.pbix?dl=0

Comment: could you please attached your final output file.

Comment: can you please advise anyone.

Comment: I am checking your file.

Comment: You have created Function not sure why. You need to create a new measure and use the above code. Please get the updated pbix file here- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t__QgMky7d6D0-gxTUSCY_AygUUhog5-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. it's working now. Sorry for the inconvenience . I am new to power bi that's the reason I miss understood. What is different between function and new measure. could you please advise. How apply the chart based on the your final output. I would like to see no of items "okay" and no of items "not okay" .

Comment: I want to see the final output in my actual data sheet(file name:your table _2)against the code and item. How can I achieve my requirements without measure.?That's maybe help incase if I want build some additional requirements in the data file and chart.

Comment: when I try to copy your measure into my actual data I am receiving the following error message. "
 Error DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type". What it's mean by? I am already covert data type as a "Text".

Comment: Hi, Good morning. Sorry I missed your message. The actual error message is "DAX don't support comparing values of type integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function convert on the value". Herewith attached the snapshot of the error message.https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqlpawn4wsf9ink/NEWMEASURE%20ERROR.PNG?dl=0  .Sorry I can't attached the original file. Could you please advise.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time and effort . It's working well. I like the code. The same code can apply measure and columns. That's really great